# Offset for sectional navigation on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Problem -
I have a section on my page (which is not in the view as soon as the page loads). I have added a div with an ID (say 'section1'), so that when the user enters "www.mywebsiteurl.com/#section1", the corresponding div is brought into view for the user. Until this point everything is working perfectly fine.
Now the main issue that I am trying to resolve is, I need an offset from the top (since I have a fixed navigation bar on the top) so that the content of the section is not behind the navigation bar, but starts just below it.
I need this behaviour for when the page loads and the url entered by the user is "www.mywbsiteurl.com/#section1".

NOTE: I want the section to have an offset as soon as the page loads with the url -
'www.mywebsiteurl.com/#section1'

Current Behaviour -

[image: Current behaviour]

Expected Behaviour -

[image: Expected behaviour]

Comment: what if you add a padding top bor your body container (like having a padding top with the same height of your appbar)

Comment: Then if a user is scrolling normally, the section would look very odd.

Comment: You could add a sibling <div> element before the <div id='section1'> element and set it to the height offset you want. Then you could make sure the div is transparent.  I think you could also add top margin to your <div id='section1'> element.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. This did help resolve.